# c# Progressbar without backgroundworker

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using COM-automation to write-out data to an already-open Word-document.

As this operation takes quite sometime I'd like to show a progressbar to the user.

It is not possible to do the data-writeout in a backgroundworker, because this will cause the Word-application to throw exception rpc_e_servercall_retrylater even with MessageFilter implemented. I've learned this is due to Words foreground thread has trouble communicating with background thread.

Is it possible to turn it the other way around and instead use a new thread to display the progressbar? I've tried to open a new winform with only the progressbar inside it, and open it on it's own thread, but it is not updating.

Other ideas?

Comment: Can you use Invoke from the background worker thread to have the work dispatched and run on the main UI thread?

Comment: if i'm not wrong backgroundworker expose progress event in there you may update your progress bar.WinForm are STA and when you are using another thread there's issue to comunicate and you may face cross thread exception...coz control stay into a trhead background worker process data into another.

Comment: i have done something few month ago let me check so i can post you some detailed infos.

Answer (score 0):

here a little snippet that i hope could help you

```
 private void BackgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   string S = Convert.ToString(e.UserState);
   Label1.Text = S;
   ProgressBar1.PerformStep();
   S = null;
}




 Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.ProgressChanged
    Dim S As String = CType(e.UserState, String)
    Label1.Text = S
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    S = Nothing
End Sub
```